# Find the source files referencing undefined symbol in shared library

Tags: c++, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I have a shared library (ELF format, I suppose) built from C++ source code. The library is built in debug mode.

Given an undefined symbol of this library I'd like to determine the source file(-s) (or an object file(-s)) it came from.

How can it be done? (I suppose it is quite possible for debug version of the library.)

Recursive grep is not an option because I'm interested only in the source files the library consist of. The undefined symbol may come from an external header file, so greping the source code of the library itself will not find anything.

Comment: Recursive grep through the source.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer a little bit? I think of something like using readelf of ldd for this purpose.

Comment: @stark Thank you for the comment, but the source itself may not contain the symbol - the symbol may come from an external header file.

Comment: Header files don't cause that error. Only use of the symbol will.

Comment: @stark No, there may not be any direct usage of the symbol - for example, a macro is used throughout the sources. This macro will be replaced with the symbol during preprocessing.

Comment: An undefined symbol error is a link time error and is usually a missing library. Google the symbol name and you might find which library.

Answer (score 3):

Your shared library, built with debug info, references an undefined external
variable, like the example I'm just going to build:

**foo.cpp**

```
 namespace bar {
     extern int undefined;
 };

 int foo()
 {
     return bar::undefined;
 }
```

I'm putting the undefined symbol in a namespace just to get a case where it's
name-mangled to the linker, since you're talking about C++.

Compile and link, with debug info:

```
 $ g++ -shared -g -fPIC -o libfoo.so foo.cpp
```

Here it is in the library's symbol table, raw:

```
 $ nm --undefined-only libfoo.so | grep undefined
                  U _ZN3bar9undefinedE
```

and demangled:

```
 $ nm -C --undefined-only libfoo.so | grep undefined
                  U bar::undefined
```

Now if we dump the debug-info we see this:

```
$ readelf --debug-dump=info libfoo.so
Contents of the .debug_info section:

  Compilation Unit @ offset 0x0:
   Length:        0x6d (32-bit)
   Version:       4
   Abbrev Offset: 0x0
   Pointer Size:  8
 <0><b>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
    <c>   DW_AT_producer    : (indirect string, offset: 0x0): GNU C++14 7.3.0 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong
    <10>   DW_AT_language    : 4    (C++)
    <11>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x8f): foo.cpp
    <15>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0x74): /home/imk/develop/so/scrap
    <19>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x5ba
    <21>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0xf
    <29>   DW_AT_stmt_list   : 0x0
 <1><2d>: Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_namespace)
    <2e>   DW_AT_name        : bar
    <32>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <33>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 1
    <34>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x48>
 <2><38>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <39>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x6a): undefined
    <3d>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <3e>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 2
    <3f>   DW_AT_linkage_name: (indirect string, offset: 0x57): _ZN3bar9undefinedE
    <43>   DW_AT_type        : <0x48>
    <47>   DW_AT_external    : 1
    <47>   DW_AT_declaration : 1
 <2><47>: Abbrev Number: 0
 <1><48>: Abbrev Number: 4 (DW_TAG_base_type)
    <49>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 4
    <4a>   DW_AT_encoding    : 5    (signed)
    <4b>   DW_AT_name        : int
 <1><4f>: Abbrev Number: 5 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <50>   DW_AT_external    : 1
    <50>   DW_AT_name        : foo
    <54>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <55>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 5
    <56>   DW_AT_linkage_name: (indirect string, offset: 0x4f): _Z3foov
    <5a>   DW_AT_type        : <0x48>
    <5e>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x5ba
    <66>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0xf
    <6e>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 1 byte block: 9c     (DW_OP_call_frame_cfa)
    <70>   DW_AT_GNU_all_call_sites: 1
 <1><70>: Abbrev Number: 0
```

in which our symbol `_ZN3bar9undefinedE` is described by entry `<2>` in the
first (and only) compilation unit that was compiled for `libfoo.so`. It's
linkage name is given by the record:

```
<3f>   DW_AT_linkage_name: (indirect string, offset: 0x57): _ZN3bar9undefinedE
```

So, to get the name of the source file(s) in which `bar::undefined` is
referenced, we want to:-

Extract from the debug info all blocks of lines like:

```
 ...Compilation Unit...
 ...
 ...
 ..._ZN3bar9undefinedE...
```

Then out of *them*, extract all blocks like:

```
 ...DW_TAG_compile_unit...
 ...
 ...DW_AT_comp_dir...
```

Then out of *those* blocks, print the last two lines. Here is one way - very likely
not the most expert way - of doing it:

```
$ readelf --debug-dump=info libfoo.so | awk '/Compilation Unit/, /_ZN3bar9undefinedE/' | awk '/DW_TAG_compile_unit/,/DW_AT_comp_dir/' | grep -B1 'DW_AT_comp_dir' 
    <11>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x8f): foo.cpp
    <15>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0x74): /home/imk/develop/so/scrap
```

We get 1 hit (of course, since only one source file was compiled), telling us that `_ZN3bar9undefinedE`,
a.k.a `bar::undefined`, is referenced in `foo.cpp`, which was compiled in build-directory `/home/imk/develop/so/scrap`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But for some reason the symbol is not present in the readelf --debug-dump=info output. Though it is present in the nm --undefined-only output.

Comment: Looks like the library may not contain the full DWARF debug info this relies on. Or possibly my awking slips up in your case. The path of the awker is strewn with banana skins. Can't help more without building your library.

Comment: I've greped the whole readelf --debug-dump=info output - it doesn't contain the symbol. Looks like the lack of debug info info.